# FreePBX 2.10 odbc storage

Tags: asterisk, freepbx

I would like to store voicemessages over odbc to mysql database.
Is app_voicemail compiled with odbc storage support?

This question cause setup in:

**- "FreePBX 2.11" ask me to enable file-storage or odbc-storage' 

   - "FreePBX 2.10" same question is not asked.**

Maybe cause support only 'file-storage'?

When i leave a message in vocalmail, in the log there is no trace of 'sql insert'.

In all examples that I've seen, where is the sql statement to insert in the table the row of voicemessage?

```
ODBC DSN Settings
-----------------


  Name:   asterisk
  DSN:    asterisk-connector
  Last connection attempt: 1970-01-01 01:00:00
Pooled: No
Connected: Yes
-----------------
root@pbx:~ $ isql asterisk root passw0rd
+---------------------------------------+
| Connected!                            |
|                                       | 
| sql-statement                         |
| help [tablename]                      |
| quit                                  |
|                                       |
+---------------------------------------+
SQL>
-----------------
/etc/asterisk/func_odbc.conf
[SQL]
dsn=asterisk-connector
readsql=${ARG1}
-----------------
/etc/asterisk/res_odbc.conf
[asterisk]
enabled => yes
dsn => asterisk-connector
username => root
password => passw0rd
pooling => no
limit => 1
pre-connect => yes
-----------------
/etc/odbc.ini
[asterisk-connector]
Driver = MySQL
Description = MySQL connection to .asterisk. database 
Server = localhost
Port = 3306
User = root
Password = --------
Database = asterisk
Option = 3
Socket = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
-----------------
/etc/asterisk/voicemail.conf
odbcstorage=asterisk
odbctable=voicemessages
-----------------
```

Answer (score 0):

ODBC storage depend from asterisk module. Asterisk have be compiled with voicemail-odbc enabled

It have very small relation with freepbx web. It should work if module present and configured.